# C: Detecting when netcat has quit

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, infinite-loop, netcat

I have a server thread that is receiving messages from a client that is using NetCat, however when I quit netcat (Either with CTRL-D or CTRL-C) on the client, the server gets stuck in an infinite loop. The server loop looks something like:

```
while((recv(socket, message, 1024, 0) >= 0){
   //Do work with message
}
```

I think the work is irrelevant here as it is just some string comparing, but like I said when I quit it seems that this loop just goes infinitely. I have heard that NetCat quitting is effectively an EOF, but how would I check for that and break the loop?

Comment: EOF is signaled by `recv` returning zero.

Comment: Ok, when reading zero bytes you can assume that the socket was closed on the other end and you may cease trying to receive data now.... You should difference between < 0 and == 0, to handle errors properly - and save the return code, otherwise you do not know, how many bytes you have read (important for processing your data)

Comment: @zwol thanks, that was it. I just had to make my loop check for > 0 instead of >= 0

Comment: Do heed @Ctx's advice: You will not receive a null terminator or any other "end of message" indicator in the data from the client -- unless the client explicitly provides it (and, to protect from buffer overflows, you should never trust your client to do so anyway). Hence, you should always record the number of bytes actually received, and ensure you only process the buffer up to that point.